# Polynomials decomposition into irreduceables

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

I've been trying to find the composition to irreduceables of the following polynomials with no much success:
X^2 +1 over the field F7
and X^2-2 over the field F5

Is there any method/algorithms I could use in order to solve this problem ?
Can it be done using euclides algorithm and finding GCD ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

Hint: your polynomials have degrees 2. So, if any of them has a proper divisor, then this divisor has degree 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still haven't got a clue

Comment: Try to prove that a polynomial of degree 2 is not irreducible iff it has a root.

Comment: I know that there is some number a in F5 (for example) such that the polynomial x-a divides (X^2+1) iff f(a) = 0 (i.e - a is a root of f(x) )

Comment: Ok , I got it ( I think ) , but I still have a question -
for (X^2-2) over F2 , one root is  a=3, so i've got (x+3) . I could I found the other irreduceable polynomial besides (x+3)?

Comment: A polynomial $x^2+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb F_7$, so it should be irreducible. A polynomial $x^2-2$ has no roots in $\mathbb F_5$, so it should be irreducible too.